# Should a web service return an error message if it receives unknown parameters?

Tags: code-quality, web-services, error-handling

I have a web service which allows to retrieve users: `http://example.com/users`. It returns a list of users.

That service accepts a number of parameters (`age`, `gender`) to select which users to retrieve. Examples:

- `http://example.com/users?age=34`
- `http://example.com/users?gender=male`

Should that service return an error message  if the client is passing an *unknown* parameter? Example:

```
>>> GET http://example.com/users?cylinders=16 
<<< 400 Bad Request
<<< { 'message' : "Invalid parameter 'cylinders'" }
```

(To me it's clear that a web service should validate the parameters it receives, but the case of unknown parameters is not clear to me)

Answer (score 6):

Technically, such checking requires an additional step. You have to list all the parameters, and compare this list with the list of allowed ones. Then, if you decide to accept an additional parameter, you have to change this list, requiring even more work. All this code has to be tested as well.

What's the benefit? The benefit is that a programmer who made a typo such as:

```
                             ↓↓
http://example.com/users?gendre=male
```

will immediately see a helpful error message, instead of receiving the list of *all* users and wondering why is the filter not working. That's great, and I wish all APIs were that helpful and programmer-friendly.

**It's up to you to decide whether this benefit is worth the effort of writing additional code and tests.**

One of the cases where you shouldn't care is when you develop the client libraries yourself. If you provide those libraries in most popular languages (Java, Python, Ruby, C++, C#, ObjectiveC, PHP), it may not be that useful to handle the case where a non-supported parameter was specified.

Comment: Actually this question can be treated as a more generic one: "how far should you go into error handling?". As you answered, it all depends on how user-friendly you want to be. I don't agree with your latest remark though. Sure it would be less important if you're developing the client libraries, but in the case of a typo, you would be glad that your programmer-friendly error handling is existing... and anyway you never know who may need a client library in which language. in the end, it's indeed always the same dicussion of ROI: is it really worth it ?

Comment: I guess I'm selfish that way, but I actually care *more* when I'm the one who has to personally deal with bad/nonexistent error messages.

Comment: @LaurentS.: if you're developing the client libraries, *you* will be the only one making typos in a context of specific languages. Of course, someone could start developing a client library for Ada or COBOL, but this won't happen too often.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head there: Actually, the reason that got me thinking about that is that one of our clients made exactly the _typo_ you were talking about and was wondering about the filter not working.